# Make the size of the TabWidget bigger

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I have some default size for the content and the tabwidget, well I have custom views in the tabwidget and I want to make him a little bit bigger. How can I do this ? also I need to know how to change the gap between tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the layout android.R.layout.tab_content source as a template. You can do something easy like increase the padding or margin, or just about anything you want. When you create your tabs with newTabSpec, set your custom layout as the indicator.